# Display a different "p" tag based on a value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, return-value

I'm looking for help for a function in javascript or via the jquery framework which seems easy but I can't. I want to display a "p" tag according to a value present in the document, this value is dynamic.

Here is what I tried:

html

```
<label class="labeltal">Types of Course:                                        
<p style="display: none;" id="shortc" value="1">SHORT COURSE</p> 
<p style="display: none;" id="medco" value="2">MEDIUM COURSE</p>
<p style="display: none;" id="lonco" value="3">LONG COURSE</p> 
</label>

<td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
<div class="d-inline-flex">
<p class="MinRounds" id="nbcp" name="MinRounds" onkeyup="noumberCoups(event)"></p>
</div>
</td>
```

javascript test 1

```
<script> 
function noumberCoups(event) {
    var nbCoups = event.target.value;
    if (nbCoups > 25){
        document.getElementById("lonco").style.display = "block";
    }else if(nbCoups >= 25){
  document.getElementById("medco").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("shortc").style.display = "block";
    }  
    console.log(nbCoups);   
};
</script>
```

javascript test 2

```
<script> 
let nbCoups = document.getElementById("nbcp").textContent;
//let nbCoups = $('#nbcp').text();

let p = document.getElementById('nbcp');
let text = p.textContent;
let nbCoups = Number(text);

if (nbCoups > 25) {
document.getElementById("lonco").style.display = "block";

}else if(nbCoups >= 25){
  document.getElementById("medco").style.display = "block";

}else{
   document.getElementById("shortc").style.display = "block";
 
   }
</script>
```

javascript test 3

```
<script>
let nbCoups= $('#nbcp').text();
   if (nbCoups> 25) {
     document.getElementById("lonco").style.display = "block";

   }else if(nbCoups>= 25){
     document.getElementById("medco").style.display = "block";

  }else{
     document.getElementById("shortc").style.display = "block";
  }

</script>
```

javascript incremented value id="nbcp"

```
$(document).ready(function() {           

let nbcoup = 0;
document.getElementById("nbcp").innerText = nbcoup;
let pts = 0;
document.getElementById("point").innerText = pts;
../..

  $('.draggable').draggable({
                helper: 'clone',
                cursor: 'move',
                scope: "#paper , #metal , #decor",
                grid: [2, 1],                          
            })

 $("#dropzone").droppable({
    scope: "#paper , #metal , #decor",
    drop: function(event, ui) { 
    if (ui.draggable.attr("alt") == "target") 
      {
       n = 1;
      p = 5;
     pap++;
     } 
../..

nbcoup = nbcoup + n;
pts = pts + p;

document.getElementById("nbcp").innerText = nbcoup;
../..
}
../..
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is pretty simple, step:

- Create function
- Add onChange to input (i use input for snippet)
- In the function add option to select
- optional : add function for remove option (just for snippet)

Example:

Full code by codepen (this snippet only work with your codepen):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { //fonction qui exectute le script        
            //console.log(document);
        const selectbox = document.getElementById("ConditionCourseId");

        let nbcoup = 0; //Nombre de coup 
        document.getElementById("nbcp").innerText = nbcoup;
        let pts = 0; //Nombre de points
        document.getElementById("point").innerText = pts;
        let pap = 0; //Nombre de cible papier
        document.getElementById("papier").innerText = pap;
        let met = 0; //Nombre de métal 
        document.getElementById("metal").innerText = met;
        let minipap = 0; //Nombre de cible papier
        document.getElementById("minipapier").innerText = minipap;
        let minimet = 0; //Nombre de métal 
        document.getElementById("minimetal").innerText = minimet;
        let plt = 0; //Nombre de métal poper
        document.getElementById("plate").innerText = plt;
        let bob = 0; //Nombre de métal minipoper
        document.getElementById("bobber").innerText = bob;
        let nosh = 0; //Nombre de noshoot 
        document.getElementById("targetNS").innerText = nosh;
        let n = 0;
        let p = 0;
        let decorsvg = document.getElementById("decorsvg")
        
        
        
            $('.draggable').draggable({ //fonction qui rend les elements draggable
                helper: 'clone',
                cursor: 'move',
                scope: "#paper , #metal , #decor",
                grid: [2, 1],
                // handle: "draggable"              
            })
            
            
            $("#dropzone").droppable({ //fonction qui rend la zone droppable
                //accept: "#objet1, #objet2 , #objet3 , #objet4",           
                scope: "#paper , #metal , #decor",
                drop: function(event, ui) { //fonction qui gere les evenements de drop
                    if (ui.draggable.attr("alt") == "popper") {
                        n = 1;
                        p = 5;
                        met++;
                    } else if (ui.draggable.attr("alt") == "minipopper") {
                        n = 1;
                        p = 5;
                        minimet++;
                    } else if (ui.draggable.attr("alt") == "plate") {
                        n = 1;
                        p = 5;
                        plt++;
                    } else if (ui.draggable.attr("alt") == "target") {
                        n = 2;
                        p = 10;
                        pap++;
                    } else if (ui.draggable.attr("alt") == "minitarget") {
                        n = 2;
                        p = 10;
                        minipap++;
                    } else if (ui.draggable.attr("alt") == "bobber") {
                        n = 2;
                        p = 10;
                        bob++;
                    } else if (ui.draggable.attr("alt") == "targetNS") {
                        n = 0;
                        p = 0;
                        nosh++;
                    } else {
                        n = 0;
                        p = 0;
                    }
                    
                    nbcoup = nbcoup + n;
                    pts = pts + p;
                    
                    document.getElementById("nbcp").innerText = nbcoup; //ligne qui pemettent d'écrire dans le tableau en positif
                    Which(nbcoup);                  
                    function Which(el){
                      removeOption(selectbox);
                      let newOption = new Option();
                       if (el > 25) {
                         newOption.text='LONG COURSE';
                         newOption.value='3';
                         newOption.id="lonco";
                       }else if(el == 25){
                         newOption.text='MEDIUM COURSE';
                         newOption.value='2';
                         newOption.id="medco";   
                      }else{
                         newOption.text='SHORT COURSE';
                         newOption.value='1';
                         newOption.id="shortc";      
                      }
                      selectbox.add(newOption);
                    }
                    document.getElementById("point").innerText = pts;
                    document.getElementById("metal").innerText = met;
                    document.getElementById("papier").innerText = pap;
                    document.getElementById("minimetal").innerText = minimet;
                    document.getElementById("minipapier").innerText = minipap;
                    document.getElementById("plate").innerText = plt;
                    document.getElementById("bobber").innerText = bob;
                    document.getElementById("targetNS").innerText = nosh;
                    
                    let redrag = $(ui.helper).clone().removeClass('draggable') //variable qui enleve la class du l'élément cloné et qui redonne la fontion draggable aux clones
                    redrag.draggable({
                        containment: 'parent',
                        cursor: 'move',                                     
                        grid: [2, 2],
                        snap: true,
                        snapTolerance: 5,
                        
                    });


                    //fonction qui permet de mettre l'image au premier avec z-index
                    $(this).append(redrag);
                    $("img").click(function() { 
                        let maxZindex = 0;
                        $("img").each(function() {
                            let z = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'));
                            if (isNaN(z)) z = 0;
                            if (z > maxZindex) maxZindex = z;
                        });
                    //attribuer un z-index supérieur à l'élément cliqué
                    $(this).css('z-index', maxZindex + 1);
                });

                    //fonction qui permet de mettre le svg au premier avec z-index 
                    $(this).append(redrag);
                    $("svg").click(function() {   
                        // console.log(this)   ;                  
                        let maxZindex = 0;
                        $("svg").each(function() {
                            let z = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'));
                            if (isNaN(z)) z = 0;
                            if (z > maxZindex) maxZindex = z;
                        });
                    //attribuer un z-index supérieur à l'élément cliqué
                    $(this).css('z-index', maxZindex + 1);
                });
                    
                    
                    if ( $(this).find("img").addClass("removable") ) { //fonction qui permet d'ajouter une class a l'image pour la supprimer avec le button reset
                };


                      if ( $(this).find("svg").addClass("removable") ) { //fonction qui permet d'ajouter une class a le svg pour la supprimer avec le button reset
                  };

                         $(this).find("svg").dblclick(function() { //fonction qui supprime un élément svg de la zone droppable par l'action double click
                             $(this).remove();                        
                         });



                    $(this).find("img").dblclick(function() { //fonction qui supprime un élément image de la zone droppable par l'action double click
                        $(this).remove();
                        if (ui.draggable.attr("alt") == "popper") {
                            n = 1;
                            p = 5;
                            met--;
                        } else if (ui.draggable.attr("alt") == "minipopper") {
                            n = 1;
                            p = 5;
                            minimet--;
                        } else if (ui.draggable.attr("alt") == "plate") {
                            n = 1;
                            p = 5;
                            plt--;
                        } else if (ui.draggable.attr("alt") == "target") {
                            n = 2;
                            p = 10;
                            pap--;
                        } else if (ui.draggable.attr("alt") == "minitarget") {
                            n = 2;
                            p = 10;
                            minipap--;
                        } else if (ui.draggable.attr("alt") == "bobber") {
                            n = 2;
                            p = 10;
                            bob--;
                        } else if (ui.draggable.attr("alt") == "targetNS") {
                            n = 0;
                            p = 0;
                            nosh--;
                        } else {
                            n = 0;
                            p = 0;
                        }
                        
                        nbcoup = nbcoup - n;
                        pts = pts - p;
                        document.getElementById("nbcp").innerText = nbcoup; //ligne qui pemettent d'écrire dans le tableau en négatif
                        document.getElementById("point").innerText = pts;
                        document.getElementById("metal").innerText = met;
                        document.getElementById("papier").innerText = pap;
                        document.getElementById("minimetal").innerText = minimet;
                        document.getElementById("minipapier").innerText = minipap;
                        document.getElementById("plate").innerText = plt;
                        document.getElementById("bobber").innerText = bob;
                        document.getElementById("targetNS").innerText = nosh;
                       
                    });
                }
            });

            $("#reset").on("click", function() { // fonction du boutton reset pour supprmer tout les elements clone draggés dans la zone possedant la classe removable 
                $('.removable').remove();
                nbcoup = 0;
                pts = 0;
                met = 0;
                minimet = 0;
                plt = 0;
                pap = 0;
                minipap = 0;
                bob = 0;
                nosh = 0;
                document.getElementById("nbcp").innerText = nbcoup; //ligne qui pemettent d'écrire dans le tableau a zéro
                document.getElementById("point").innerText = pts;
                document.getElementById("metal").innerText = met;
                document.getElementById("papier").innerText = pap;
                document.getElementById("minimetal").innerText = minimet;
                document.getElementById("minipapier").innerText = minipap;
                document.getElementById("plate").innerText = plt;
                document.getElementById("bobber").innerText = bob;
                document.getElementById("targetNS").innerText = nosh;
                exit();
            });
            
            
            



        });

    $("#elements").accordion({ //Fonction pour la liste déroulante des cibles et accessoires
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "fill"

    });

    $( "#accordion-resizer" ).resizable({
    
        resize: function() {
            $( "#elements," ).accordion( "refresh" );
        }
    }); 


//script pour capturer l'image du stage
function uploadFile() {
window.scrollTo(0, 0); //scroll page entiere du haut en bas 
        html2canvas(document.getElementById("main"),{scale: 2}).then(function(canvas){ //creation image avec scale: 2-> qualité X2
            let doc = new jsPDF();
            // doc.setFontSize(40); //taille titre
                    // doc.text(40, 25, "TSV STAGE MAKER") // titre
                    doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.9), 'JPEG', 5, 10, 200, 270); //'JPEG', 15(Gauche), 10 (Haut), 180 (Droite), 280 (Bas)                            
                    let blob = doc.output('blob');  

                    let image = ("image=" + canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.9));
                    let stagename = document.querySelector('[name="stagename"]');
                    let stagenumber = document.querySelector('[name="stagenumber"]');
                    let FirearmId = document.querySelector('[name="FirearmId"]');
                    let TrgtTypeId = document.querySelector('[name="TrgtTypeId"]');
                    let ScoringId = document.querySelector('[name="ScoringId"]');
                    let StartOn = document.querySelector('[name="StartOn"]');
                    let StartPos = document.getElementById("StartPos");
                    let Descriptn = document.getElementById("Descriptn");
                    let CourseId = document.querySelector('[name="CourseId"]');
                    let MatchsId = document.querySelector('[name="MatchsId"]'); 
                    let MaxPoints = document.querySelector('[name="MaxPoints"]');
                    let MinRounds = document.querySelector('[name="MinRounds"]');   
                    let TrgtPaper = document.querySelector('[name="TrgtPaper"]');
                    let TrgtPlates = document.querySelector('[name="TrgtPlates"]');
                    let TrgtPenlty = document.querySelector('[name="TrgtPenlty"]');
                    let TrgtPopper = document.querySelector('[name="TrgtPopper"]'); 
                    let bobber = document.getElementById("bobber"); 
                    let StringCnt = document.querySelector('[name="StringCnt"]');
                    let ReportOn = document.querySelector('[name="ReportOn"]'); 
                    let Token = document.querySelector('[name="_token"]');
                    let sectionstage = document.getElementById("datastage");    
                    let formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('file', blob);
                    formData.append('jpeg', image);                     
                    formData.append('stagename', stagename.value);
                    formData.append('stagenumber', stagenumber.value);
                    formData.append('FirearmId', FirearmId.value);
                    formData.append('TrgtTypeId', TrgtTypeId.value);
                    formData.append('ScoringId', ScoringId.value);
                    formData.append('StartOn', StartOn.value);
                    formData.append('StartPos', StartPos.innerText);
                    formData.append('Descriptn', Descriptn.innerText);
                    formData.append('CourseId', CourseId.value);
                    formData.append('MatchsId', MatchsId.value);
                    formData.append('MaxPoints', MaxPoints.innerText);
                    formData.append('MinRounds', MinRounds.innerText);
                    formData.append('TrgtPaper', TrgtPaper.innerText);
                    formData.append('TrgtPlates', TrgtPlates.innerText);
                    formData.append('TrgtPenlty', TrgtPenlty.innerText);
                    formData.append('TrgtPopper', TrgtPopper.innerText);
                    formData.append('bobber', bobber.innerText);
                    formData.append('StringCnt', StringCnt.value);
                    formData.append('ReportOn', ReportOn.value);
                    formData.append('_token', Token.value);
                    formData.append('datastage', sectionstage.innerHTML);
                    console.log(formData);
                    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                            alertify.success('Your Stage has been successfully saved !');
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    xhr.open("post", "{{ path('app_stage_create') }}",); 
                    xhr.send(formData);
                });
}


            // script pour telecharger le pdf direct sur pc
            function savPDF(){
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                html2canvas(document.getElementById("main"),{scale: 2}).then(function(canvas){
                    let doc = new jsPDF();
                // doc.setFontSize(5);
                // doc.text(40, 25, "text")
                doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.9), 'JPEG', 5, 10, 200, 320);//'JPEG', 15(Gauche), 10 (Haut), 180 (Droite), 280 (Bas)
                
                doc.save("stage.pdf");  

            });
            };  


            // change COULEURS PANNEAU

       // change COULEURS PANNEAU
            function changeColor(){
                let color = document.getElementById('colorInputColor').value;               
                $("svg rect").each(function() {
                    $(".panneau1").css("fill", color);
                });
            }


            //rotation elements
            let degrees = 0;
            $(".elementRotate").click(function () {
              degrees += 10;
              $(this).css("transform", "rotate(" + degrees + "deg)");
          });




function removeOption(el) {
    while (el.options.length > 0) {
        el.remove(0);
    }
}
```

```html
                    <label class="labeltal">Types of Course:
                      <select class="noborder font-weight-bold" name="CourseId" id="ConditionCourseId" 

                      </select>
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your suggestion, but it's not dynamic.
When I set the value in hard and I reload the page it works but if the value changes dynamically the select does not change.

Comment: how you edit the value ? with input ? if yes see first example is dynamically .

Comment: The value is incremented by a script on another page, when moving a "draggable" image in a "droppable" area

Comment: So you must reload, or do you use ajax?

Comment: I can't reload the page it's the goal of using javascript and I want it to be dynamic and that it change in focus of the moved elements to at the end i use ajax to send everything in the database

Comment: if the value come from another page (with db/post/get) you must use AJAX for reload value and call function else you must reload page.

Comment: Another page is app.js

Comment: have you a live preview?

Comment: You can see part of the script on codepen, but there is still some things to fix because the script works thanks to a something that does not exist "exit ()" you will see!
https://codepen.io/tsvstagemaker/pen/wvzMMda

Comment: I add the  full code on last snippet now. copy and past to your codepen code. (i didn't past all code because is long. i just change js and selectbox html)

Comment: thank you very much @SimoneRossaini it works well, I just put the right values and the right Relational Operators

Comment: You are welcome please flag the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It's unnecessary to have different p tags for the different cases.
It would be better to change the content of the tag dynamically.

Here's how you could do it.
I created the event object since I don't know where you are getting it and I replaced the value in the 'Medium' option since it was the same as the 'Long' one.

```js
let t = {
  target: { value: 30 }
}

function noumberCoups(event) {
    var nbCoups = event.target.value;
    const p = document.getElementById('course-type');
    
    if (nbCoups > 25){
        p.innerHTML = 'Long course'
    } else if(nbCoups >= 15){
        p.innerHTML = 'Medium course'
    } else {
        p.innerHTML = 'Short course'
    }  
    console.log(nbCoups);   
};

noumberCoups(t);
```

```html
<label class="labeltal">Types of Course:                                       <p id="course-type"></p> 
</label>
```

Comment: it doesn't work but I may have made a mistake.
I add <p class = "MinRounds" id = "nbcp" name = "MinRounds" onkeyup = "noumberCoups()"> </p>

I also added the way in which the "p" id = "nbcp" is incremented above in the first request

Comment: How are you getting the value passed to the function?
It might not work for a number of reasons. You should adapt the function to suit the rest of your code, but the concept is the same: change the innerHTML of the p tag according to the value passed to the function.
Again, without more information we cannot help you.

Comment: Hello   Edy Espinal,  Simone Rossaini has found the solution and it works well.
I put a codepen code link in my first question